# How to prevent modules code execution from imported module in python?

Tags: python, import

Given I have files

testone.py

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    from testtwo import Fu
class Foo:
    def bar(self):
        print 'barrr'
```

testtwo.py

```
class Fu:
    def baz(self):
        print 'baz'

Fu().baz() # function call within module
```

How do you import class Fu from file testtwo.py without running the function called within module testtwo.py?  I tried resolving the issue checking the name.  As is running the file testone.py will result in the shell printing out baz.

Comment: by definition i guess this is a repost. of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6757192/importing-a-function-from-a-class-in-another-file

Comment: you can't supress it - python modules are defined that way (i.e. they execute when imported). If you don't like that feature change your design !

Comment: It may have the same answer, but semantically, it's a different question.

Comment: @AaronHall why I said by definition. Thanks for seeing my point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to prevent modules code execution from module in python?

You can't, when you import a module, it runs everything that is called in the global scope.

You can change it so that it's easy to call or not:

```
def main():
    Fu().baz()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And then when you want it called you import it and call `main()` and it will still automatically run when you run it as the main module.