# How to inherit class from different file?

Tags: python, inheritance, jupyter-notebook

I have two files:

> fig.py

```
import math
PI=math.pi

class Fig:
    def __init__(self):   
        self.name= " "
```

And

> circle.py

```
class Circle(Fig):
    def __init__(self, radius):
        self.name= "Circle"
        self.data= ["Radius: ", radius]
```

But I am trying to load them I whenever I try it *jupyter-notebook* throws the error:

> NameError: name 'Fig' is not defined

I have tried using `import fig` at the beggining of *circle.py* and it does not work, neither does running both files. They are both in the same directory.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Ok it's not exactly clear what's going wrong because you haven't sent us precisely what you are doing, but here is my guess. If your `circle.py` file is as follows

```
import fig
class Circle(Fig):
    def __init__(self, radius):
        self.name= "Circle"
        self.data= ["Radius: ", radius]
```

This will break because python doesn't know where to find `Fig`. If instead you write

```
import fig
class Circle(fig.Fig):
    def __init__(self, radius):
        self.name= "Circle"
        self.data= ["Radius: ", radius]
```

or

```
from fig import Fig
class Circle(Fig):
    def __init__(self, radius):
        self.name= "Circle"
        self.data= ["Radius: ", radius]
```

Everything should work fine. This is because you either have to tell python the namespace through which it can access the class (my first solution) or explicitly import the class (my second solution). The same logic applies if you want to use `PI`:

```
import fig
class Circle(fig.Fig):
    def __init__(self, radius):
        self.name= "Circle"
        self.data= ["Radius: ", radius]
        #use PI from fig.py by informing python of namespace
        self.circumference = 2.*fig.PI*radius
```

or

```
from fig import Fig, PI
class Circle(fig):
    def __init__(self, radius):
        self.name= "Circle"
        self.data= ["Radius: ", radius]
        #PI is now explicitly imported so don't need namespace
        self.circumference = 2.*PI*radius
```

Comment: With both options inheritance works but the first two lines do not. If I *run circle* PI is not defined. If I run both I get *SyntaxError: invalid syntax*.

Answer (score 4):

You need to do `from fig import FIG` in your *circle.py*. Also make sure that you have `__init__.py` file present in the folder which is having *circle.py* and *fig.py*.

Please also take as look at:

- [Importing a function from a class in another file?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6757225/2063361)
- [What is `__init__.py` for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for)

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the class `Fig` from `fig.py` in `circle.py`.

If you just import the module `fig`, you must access the class `Fig` through the respective namespace:

```
class Circle(fig.Fig):
    <snip>
```

If you want to use the class name directly, import it using `from fig import Fig`.

Answer (score 0):

```
from packagename.fig import Fig

class Circle(Fig):
    def __init__(self, radius):
        self.name = "Circle"
        self.data = ["Radius: ", radius]
```

Where `packagename` is your actual package name.