# Can I copy across selected python functions and class methods from one file to another file?

Tags: python, automation

I have a python file that is a collection `functions`, `classes` with `methods` etc.  I need to parse it so that I can just extract out the  specified `functions` and `classes` including the `methods` that I need for the purpose of over-riding them.

Is there a `parser` that can parse `python` code well for this kind of requirement? Will the inbuilt `ast` module help me?

For example:

Input: Main.py

```
def f_one():
    """
    """
    pass

class c_one():
    """
    """
    def m_one():
    """
    """
    pass

    def m_two():
    """
    """
    pass
    def m_three():
    """
    """
    pass

class c_two():
    def m_one():
    """
    """
    pass
```

Goal is to just copy across `f_one`, `c_one` and `m_one`, more generally the code (function, class etc) that I specify.

Output: Copy.py

```
def f_one():
    """
    """
    pass

class c_one():
    """
    """
    def m_one():
    """
    """
    pass
```

Comment: Do you mean `import`?

Comment: No, I am just trying to automate a copy paste work that I do normally. I just described how I copy paste :-)

Comment: So you just want to extract the name of each class and function in Main.py?

Comment: I would use [import](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html). If you only want to import a class method [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6757192/importing-a-function-from-a-class-in-another-file) might help. // edit: If you only want to pass a function from `main.py` to another function `foo()`, just do `foo(c_one.m_one)`.

Comment: I don't understand why you are copying and pasting *at all*. That is not something you should be doing.

Comment: Say for example the `Zope Framework`. It has a Template for adding a Controller, Model, Views, Queries to the framework. I can obviously create this Template once and for all. But I was trying to see if there are `Python` code `parsers` that extracts these from an existing Module for example. I am basically trying to copy pase these templates

Comment: Nothing you've said gives a reason not to use `import`. If you want to use `f_one` and `c_one` in another file, you would do `from main import f_one, c_one`.

Comment: They have to renamed :-) I am just using them as *Templates* kind of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `inspect.getsource()`

```
import inspect
import Main

objects = [Main.f_one, Main.c_one]

copy = ''

#copy objects
for obj in objects:
    copy += inspect.getsource(obj)
    copy += '\n'

with open('Copy.py', 'w') as out:
    out.write(copy)
```

This writes the full source code of `f_one` and `c_one` to Copy.py. If you only want parts of `c_one`, you would have to inspect all the members that you want seperately (e.g. `inspect.getsource(Main.c_one.m_one)`) and assemble them manually.

You can also use `inspect.getsourcelines()` to get an object's source line by line (for instance if you want only the headers).

Note that this is obviously not possible for imports from compiled files.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to import it:

```
from Main import f_one, c_one

c = c_one()
c.m_two()
```