# How to import class with all functions in Python from different file?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I created 'class V' in file 'V.py' with some functions, which I want to keep using in other projects, but when I call any of these functions I get an error that the name is not defined. I tried all solutions that I could find and nothing fixes it. Hope somebody knows what am I doing wrong..

```
class V(object):

    def magnitude(self):
        a=0
        for i in range(len(self)):
            for j in range(len(self[i])):
                a= a + self[i][j] **2
        return sqrt(a)
```

Calling a function:

```
from V import V
A = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,0,6],[7,8,9]])
print magnitude(A)
```

Error:

```
NameError: name 'magnitude' is not defined
```

Comment: What about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6757192/importing-a-function-from-a-class-in-another-file?

Comment: It should be `from V.V import magnitude`.  Then your call to magnitude will work

Comment: Try it with `print V.magnitude(A)`

Comment: You can check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20309456/call-a-function-from-another-file-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refactor your class method to take a parameter, and create an object of class before accessing the method.

```
from math import sqrt


class V(object):

    def magnitude(self, A):
        a = 0
        for i in range(len(A)):
            for j in range(len(A[i])):
                a = a + A[i][j] ** 2
        return sqrt(a)
```

```
import numpy as np
from V import V

v = V()
A = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,0,6],[7,8,9]])
print (v.magnitude(A))
```

This will work. 
The reason is you are trying to access class method without creating a class object and passing a parameter inside the method too. `self` is basically the object on which the method is being called.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I ran the code and its giving me some wierd error "TypeError: magnitude() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)". However if I run it within the original file it works without errors.

Comment: Did you change your class ? I have tested this code shouldn't break

Answer (score -2):

You should pass magnitude to class, not to method
try:

```
from V import V
A = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,0,6],[7,8,9]])
m = V(A)
print (V)
```