# what are the Best coding practice for creating python package

Tags: python-3.x, pip, package, pypi

I am creating `pypi` python package and for that i tired many solution avilable in different websites.

1. First of all I followed this [Approach1](https://www.codementor.io/@ajayagrawal295/how-to-publish-your-own-python-package-12tbhi20tf), in this approach author has created `class` and `functions` but when tried this one my package gave me an error that `no module` and `class name is not define`
2. I tired many other Approaches like this one [Approach2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QgZ7qv4Cd0Y&t=1150s) in this approach author created only `functions` without `class` and `__init__.py`
3. and then tried this one also which is very common [Approach3](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/python/python-package)

and here is important files structure provided by `pypi` officials

```
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
├── example_pkg
│   └── __init__.py
├── setup.py
└── tests
```

I am ready with my package but after spending whole night finding which one is Best coding practice? and now got confused

so my questions are as follows

1. what is the use of file `__init__.py`?
2. best practice for giving directory, class and functions names so that it will help during importing.because according to these [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6757192/importing-a-function-from-a-class-in-another-file) some people said import directory name, some said filename followed by class etc..
3. Can anyone provide me proper steps so that i can follow in upcoming packages also

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend following the Python Packaging Authorities guides and tutorials at https://packaging.python.org.

In addition, the PyPA publishes an example project skeleton that you can use as a starting point: https://github.com/pypa/sampleproject/